# Angular: Is there any need to use app.server.module.ts anymore?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am currently transforming an old Angular app to a new version (Angular 10) and there is a file in app folder called `app.server.module.ts`. However, asa far as I see, it seemsto be related to old versions (maybe AngularJS), but I am not sure how to remove this file (which changes should I made in `app.module.ts`, `app.routing.module.ts`, etc. Here is that file below:

***app.server.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [AppModule, ServerModule, ModuleMapLoaderModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

Will it be a problem to remove completely?

***Update:***
Here is the only file using this module in the entire frontend project:

***tsconfig.server.json.ts:***

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
,
  "files": [
    "main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I suggest renaming `AppServerModule` to something else, and see if it falls on your head somehow. Other than that please note that the provided code does not give any potential answerer any kind of clue as to where the problem could be. Expand your question with more details as you test around.

Comment: @MikeS. Thnaks a lot for your answer. I think of that, but as you guess, some problems may not be seen directly after running the project. For this reason I think it is good idea to know the usage of this file before changing. Actually there is no need to give extra info, because it is a file based on a structure (maybe created automatically in previous versions).

Comment: @MikeS. I also added the only file (`tsconfig.server.json.ts`) that uses this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to AngularJS but to Angular.

If you want to remove this file (without knowing the whole context of your application), you would at least need to make two changes :

Add the `bootstrap` metadata into another module (AppModule ?) as it defines the root component of your app being bootstrapped from your index.html

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Check your `main.ts` file as it might be the module used to bootstrap your application :

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppServerModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

If removing this module in benefit of your AppModule, you would as well need to add the imports `ServerModule` and  `ModuleMapLoaderModule` into its medatdata.

Comment: Thnaks for reply. Sorry, I added an update by giving the only file (`tsconfig.server.json.ts`) that uses this module. Maybe it gives an idea and that is the only place to make changes after removing that file (`app.server.module.ts`). Any idea?

Comment: exactly : change the `angularCompilerOptions ` entryModule (but you still need to change the `bootstrap` part from my answer)

Comment: **1)** In the app.modeule.ts, there is already `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` entry, so it is ok I think. **2)** Also as far as I know, there should be only one bootstrap definition as it is used on startup, is that true? **3)** In the main.ts, the bootstrap definition shows AppModule as it is in the first point: `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`. So, Is there anything to change? MAybe in the `tsconfig.server.json.ts` file?

Comment: Yes for 1 & 2. So in this situation, just change `tsconfig.server.json.ts`.

Comment: On the other hand, there is no `tsconfig.server.json.ts` file in my new app. So, waht should I do in that file?

Comment: in fact it depends on the goal of the app : this file is used to provide a server side rendered app (known as SSR). If you don't plan to use this technique to provide pre rendered pages of your app, you don't need it (you can take a look to ng-universal for more information)

Comment: I have a look at SSR and as far as I see the 2 main reason using it performance and search optimization. However, I am not sure if it is used for the last years in Angular apps. Because default template does not contain it after  creating an Angular app and it it is not used commonly, or not preferred, I do not use a rarely used approach. So, what is your suggestion? And if I do not use it, what changes I need to make extra in addition to the changes above? Maybe removing tsconfig.server.json.ts, etc. Any idea?

Comment: if you don't use it, you should just need to remove the tsconfig.server.json.ts file and your AppServerModule (and the `@angular/platform-server` & `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader` packages from your package.json). No more changes into your actual code

Comment: It seems to be ok as on https://angular.io/guide/universal.

Comment: Dear Gerome, many thanks for you help. I removed these files, but there is no @angular/platform-server & @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader packages in the  package.json. Is that normal? Or where may be these definitions?

Comment: they might be part of another angular package so you are done by now :)