# My angular router links works fine in production but not with dev:ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

My angular app is using SSR, when I run the command npm run dev:ssr the router links don't work as they refresh the browser, but when I deploy the same app to a linux server, the router links works and does not refresh the page.
Which file I need to investigate?

Comment: Can you share a project with the issue reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with an [Angular application with Server Side Rendering (SSR)](https://angular.io/guide/universal), and you notice different behavior between development and production environments, you might need to investigate:

- **`angular.json`**: This file contains configurations for different environments, like production and development. Check if there are any differences between the configurations that could cause this issue.
  See [Simple deployment options](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simple-deployment-options)
- **`server.ts`**: This file contains the Express server configuration used for SSR. If there are any middleware or configuration specific to development that might be affecting the behavior of router links, you should investigate here.
  See [Universal template engine](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-template-engine) and subsequent sections
- **`main.server.ts`** and **`app.server.module.ts`**: These files are responsible for setting up the application on the server side. Ensure that there are no differences in how the modules are imported or configured between environments.
  Although, do check first: "[Angular: Is there any need to use `app.server.module.ts` anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116652/6309)".
- **`app-routing.module.ts`**: This file contains the router configuration. Check if there are any guards or interceptors that behave differently in development mode.
  See [Set up an application](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#set-up-an-application)
- **`environment.ts`** and **`environment.prod.ts`**: These files contain the environment-specific configuration. Make sure there isn’t any configuration that affects the behavior of router links.
  See [Configure environment-specific defaults](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults)
- **`polyfills.ts`**: This file contains polyfills that might be necessary for your application to run correctly in different environments. Check if there are any polyfills that are only included in production.
  See [Enabling polyfills with CLI projects](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills-with-cli-projects)
- **`package.json`**: Check if there are any dependencies that are only included in development and not in production or vice versa. Also, make sure that the scripts section contains the correct commands for running the application in different environments.
  See [Angular package format / `package.json`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-package-format#packagejson)
- **Server Configuration**: If you are using a web server like Nginx or Apache to serve your application in production, check the server configuration to ensure that it is not affecting the behavior of the application.

Also, I would suggest checking the browser console for any errors or messages that might give clues as to why the behavior is different in the development environment. If there are specific errors, you might be able to find solutions by searching for those errors online.

Comment: thank you, the only error I see in console is bundle.js is not found in development mode.

Comment: @MuhammadArslanJamshaid Did you check the path to `bundle.js`? Check your `index.html` file and any other places where `bundle.js` might be referenced to make sure the paths are correct. Check also your build configuration in `angular.json`. It's possible that the file is not being built or is being built to a different directory in development mode. Check the `outputPath` and other configurations under the `build` and `serve` options.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the simplest and most underrated solution there is : use hash location strategy.

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

This will change your urls from this

http://localhost:4200/home

To this

http://localhost:4200/#/home

If this resolves your issue, it means your HTTP is not configured for a SPA, so either resolve that, or keep using the hash.